# can i have multiple 'on' in single GitActions workflow file?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-workflow

I want to have the multiple on in single git workflow file life following.
is this possible and if yes is it a good practice ?

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '30 5,17 * * *'
    
jobs 
-----

on:
  push:
    branches: 

jobs
-----
```

Comment: Regarding the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) it is not possible. You can use only multiple events at the top of the configuration.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible like you do it, but what you can do is something like this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '30 5,17 * * *'

jobs:
  my_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
```

However if your jobs are distinct, I'd suggest putting them into different files.